# Anonymous com.android.volley.response.errorlistener in Json

Tags: android, json, facebook, android-volley

I was learning the custom listview by using Volley provided from google.
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/

I followed exactly same code from the tutorial but I got error.

[image: Here is the error]

One thing I not followed the tutorial is was using this
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17'
to import volley lib since it's the same.

Here is my code:

```js
package ahfoo_project.ui.discoverUI;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SearchView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import butterknife.ButterKnife;
import butterknife.InjectView;
import butterknife.Optional;


public class SearchActivity extends Activity
{
    private static final String TAG = SearchActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private FeedListAdapter listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://api.androidhive.info/feed/feed.json";

    @Optional
    @InjectView(R.id.SearchTextView)
    SearchView searchTextView;

    @Optional
    @InjectView(R.id.Searchtoolbar)
    Toolbar searchToolbar;

    @Optional
    @InjectView(R.id.search_listView)
    ListView searchListview;

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        ButterKnife.inject(this);

        initializeToolbar();
        /***************************************************************************/

        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
        searchListview.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        // fetch the data from cache
        if (entry != null) try {
            String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
            try {
                parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

    }





    /**
     * Parsing json reponse and passing the data to feed view list adapter
     * */
    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initializeToolbar()
    {
        searchToolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.back_arrow);
        searchToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you add the library jar file in build path

Comment: @SohailZahid Sorry I just started to learn Android, where to add the library jar?

Comment: project>properties>JavabuildPath>Librarys>addExternalLib

Comment: if you are not geeting this check this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/

Comment: @SohailZahid i finally found out whats the problem.. Is because i using the com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.17 instead of download the jar file.. Once i download and used the jar file. It work like a charm. Thanks dude

Comment: its my pleasure your vote can help others too.

Comment: @SohailZahid omg, how to vote your comment? LOL gosh.. I am so "newbie"

Comment: haha there is a day when i am same as you..... learning is about step by step.up arrow on my url comment hidden when hover it appears.